# asterisk is appearing when using collapse rows

Tags: r, r-markdown, kable, kableextra

In the rmarkdown file below I am trying to use collapse rows. IN this case there is only 1 row but in other cases there will be more than 1 row.

When you run the file you will see an asterisk and then the number .02*. When you comment out the line "%>%  collapse_rows(columns = 1, latex_hline = "major", valign = "middle")"  the astersik goes away so it has something to do with collapse rows. How can this be fixed given that I'd like to keep the collapse rows code because in other cases there are more than 1 row and it works. I tried conditionally excluding with the if statement but that did not work.

````
---
author:
  - ""
classoption: landscape
output: 
  pdf_document:
    number_sections: false
    dev: pdf
    keep_tex: no
    toc: yes
    toc_depth: 3
  fig.pos: H
  fig.width: 11in
  fontsize: 9pt
  geometry: "left=1cm,right=1cm,top=1cm,bottom=1cm"
  fig.lp: 'Fig '
  setspace: singlespacing
  always_allow_html: yes
header-includes:
- \usepackage{amsmath}
- \usepackage{rotating}
- \usepackage{float}
- \usepackage{longtable}
- \usepackage{tabulary}
- \usepackage{array}
- \usepackage{colortbl}
- \usepackage{graphicx}
- \usepackage{booktabs}
- \usepackage{multirow}
- \usepackage[table]{xcolor}
- \usepackage{wrapfig}
- \usepackage{pdflscape}
- \usepackage{tabu}
- \usepackage{threeparttable}
- \usepackage{threeparttablex}
- \usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
- \usepackage{makecell}
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

```{r test}
library(kableExtra)
library(dplyr)
d = data.frame(g = c("A"),v = c(.02))%>%
 dplyr::mutate(    

    v = cell_spec(v, 
                                       color = ifelse(is.na(v),"black", ifelse(  abs(v) >= 1, "red", "black")), 
                                       bold=   ifelse(is.na(v),FALSE,   ifelse(  abs(v) >= .1, TRUE, FALSE)) )

 )%>% 
  dplyr::rename("test"="v" )

 kable(
      d, 
    format ="latex",
      caption = "test",
      booktabs = T,
      longtable = T,
      escape = F,
      align = "c",
      linesep=""
      ) %>% kable_styling(latex_options = c(
        "repeat_header"
        ),
        font_size=8) %>%  collapse_rows(columns = 1, latex_hline = "major", valign = "middle")

    #%>%  {if(nrow(d)>1) collapse_rows(columns = 1, latex_hline = "major", valign = "middle")} #this does not work



```
````

Answer (score 0):

This is a work around:

.... `{if(nrow(d)>1) collapse_rows(columns = 1, latex_hline = "major", valign = "middle")  else .  } %>%`